# How to add input type in Ruby On Rails 5 in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, form-helpers

I've noticed that f.text_field helper returns different input elements in development and production. In the second one type="text" is omitted for unknown reason. Adding it through the helper doesn't solve the problem.

Development

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your full name" name="request[full_name]" id="request_full_name">
```

Production

```
<input placeholder="Your full name" name="request[full_name]" id="request_full_name">
```

Did anyone have the same problem?
How can this be fixed?

P.s. other helpers like f.telephone_field, f.email_field, etc. work great.

Comment: Is this happening for all f.text_field s or just for one?

Comment: This is happening for every f.text_field in the form but only for f.text_field helper. Other helpers like f.telephone_field, f.email_field, etc. are OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for anyone tried to help.
The problem was with the configuration of htmlcompressor gem. This line

```
remove_input_attributes: true
```

must be

```
remove_input_attributes: false
```